# Cannot conver float* to float :((

Tags: c++

tengo un problema, me manda el siguiente mensaje de error
podrian brindarme su apoyo por favor :((?
El apartado de  los datos pide que datos sea con apuntador * :((
Estoy en un curso de programacion y nos dejaron este problema pero no se como continuarle, ya logre arreglar varios errores que se mostraba pero ahora no se como continuar y no logro hayar una respuesta clara ante mi problema

[Error] cannot convert 'float*' to 'float' in initialization

```
#ifndef DATOS_H
#define DATOS_H
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

class DATOS{
    public:
        //Constructor
        DATOS(int num=0);
        //Destructor
        ~DATOS(void);
        void Leer_datos(void);
        void Imprimir(void);
        //Funciones amigas
        friend float MEDIA(DATOS &objdatos);
        friend float VARIANZA(DATOS &objdatos);
        friend float DESVIACION(DATOS &objdatos);
        friend float MEDIANA(DATOS &objdatos);
        friend float MODA(DATOS &objdatos);
    
    private:
        int N;//Tamaño de la muestra
        float *datos;//vector dinamico
};

DATOS::DATOS(int num){
    N=num;
}

DATOS::~DATOS(void){
    delete [ ]datos;
    datos=nullptr;
}

void DATOS::Leer_datos(void){
    int num;
    float dat=new float[num];
    cout<<"\n\tIngrese el numero de datos: ";cin>>num;
    for(int i;i<N;i++){
        cout<<"\n\tIngrese el dato #"<<i+1<<": ";cin>>dat[i];
    }
}

void DATOS::Imprimir(void){
    cout<<N;
}

#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

El error está en la línea:

```
float dat=new float[num];
```

Te dice que en lugar de `float` debería ser `float*`:

```
float* dat=new float[num];
```

Ten en cuenta que estás trabajando con el heap. La memoria que reserves debes liberarla una vez la terminas de usar. Si la reservaste con `new`, la liberas con `delete` y si usaste `new[]`, con `delete[]`.

```
delete[] dat;
```

Aunque viendo la clase supongo que debería funcionar en conjunto con los miembros de la instancia.

Pierde la gracia usar POO si usas los métodos como funciones normales. Lo ideal sería que lo hagas así para aprovechar la POO:

```
// En el archivo de la clase

...

DATOS::Datos(int num){
    N = num;
    datos = new float[N];
}

...

void DATOS::Leer_datos(void){
    for(int i;i<N;i++){
        cout<<"\n\tIngrese el dato #"<<i+1<<": ";
        cin>>dat[i];
    }
}

// En main.cpp

int main()
{
    int num = 0;
    cout<<"\n\tIngrese el numero de datos: ";
    cin>>num;
    DATOS datos(num);
    datos.Leer_datos();
}
```

---

Por cierto, no es necesario escribir `void` dentro de los paréntesis si la función no recibe parámetros.

Ambas son formas válidas de referirse a la misma función:

```
void Imprimir();
void Imprimir(void);
```